# Java: How do I add to a base class without modifying class file

Tags: java, inheritance

I am using a Java library that has a class hierarchy:

e.g. classes C1 and C2 that both extend class B

Is there a way for me to add functionality (attributes, methods) to class B such that it will be available to the child classes C1 & C2 without modifying the 3 files?

If not, what is the right way to do this short of rewriting all 3 classes?

Comment: You'll have to modify B at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you aren't able to modify B for some reason, make an intermediary class that extends it for you:

```
public class ClassC extends ClassB {

    //additional functionality

}
```

Then it's simple:

```
public class Class1 extends ClassC {...}
```

If you can modify B, the other classes already inherit the methods, and you don't need to worry about rewriting them unless you mark the methods `abstract`

Comment: This way, you modify classes `C1` and `C2` than just modifying one single class, `B`.

Comment: Right. Which I don't want to do.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom Which part do you not want to do, and why?

Comment: I don't want to modify any of the 3 original files. I don't own the source code of those files.

Comment: Then you'll need to extend the subclasses (Or attempt decompiling them with JD-GUI)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot modify `B` then you will have to extend it, and modify `C1` and `C2` to extend your new class instead of `B`.

If you cannot modify any of these classes, then you could do something like this:

- Create `BX` extending `B` with new functionality
- Create `C1X` extending `BX`, and containing an inner `C1` object. Delegate all method calls except the new methods in `BX` to the underlying `C1` object
- Create `C2X` following the same logic as `C1X`

This ain't pretty. And might not work. For example if the new method needs to manipulate private data of the underlying objects then this won't work. But I don't think there's another way, given the restrictions. If Java had multiple inheritance it could work by `C1X` extending both `C1` and `BX`, but short of that I'm afraid this dirty solution is the best you can have. (If it even works.)

Comment: This would work but is not pretty as you say. I just had a thought that maybe this could be done cleaner with C1X extending C1 and implementing the added functionality as an interface where the interface delegates to common code. Think I'll go try this first.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom how did it go?

Comment: Posted my answer above based on yours. No votes for it so I'm not sure if anyone agreed with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to add functionality (attributes, methods) to class B such that it will be available to the child classes C1 & C2 without modifying the 3 files?

You will only have to modify the class `B`. If you add methods, they will be inherited by classes `C1` and `C2` automatically, so you don't need to modify those classes.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to modify class B. If you add a protected or public method to B, C1 and C2 will automatically be able to invoke it, without any changes required.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the question is kind of vague and it is hard to tell without knowing your intention.

If you want to enhance the behavior of your class in runtime, then you may look into something like Javassit or CGLib etc, which allow you to alter the classes and add new feature to it, without need of modifying source code of the original source.

If you are developing something, and trying to find a design that will allow you to add functionality without changing source code of existing classes, then you may look into things like Dectorator pattern.

If you simply have that three class on hand and you don't want to/not allowed to modify them but you still want to add functionality without updating them.  Then it is not possible in Java, sorry.  (A lot other languages provide such feature anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify  class `B` in any case. There can be 2 approaches to this(assuming you can modify `B`).

**First:** Make the changes you want to do in `B` directly and since `C1` and `C2` extend `B` already, the methods and fields would be available in those classes as such(only if they are `public or protected`, that is). This requires a lot of changing in `B` though.

**Second:** Have an abstract class which is extended by `B`. In this case, a small change to `B` should suffice which would be extending that abstract class. This way, everything you add to the abstract class is available to all the classes below in the hierarchy. Just make sure you don't have any abstract methods in the abstract class.

```
public abstract class ParentOfB {

    // Additional functionality
}

public class B extends ParentOfB { // The only change in B

}
```

The reason why `ParentOfB` is abstract is because you don't want any other class using those functionality without inheriting `B`. In case you need that functionality elsewhere, you can make `ParentOfB` just a normal class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I came up with. It's a variation of what Janos wrote but I think it is nicer. I do not need to change any of the classes, can re-use the extension in any of the children classes and continue to inherit from the new extended children. Still need to delegate the methods though.

So for example:
Note how D1 below already inherits from B1, C1 and B_EXTRA_IMPL

```
public class B1 {
        public void b1() {       
            System.out.println("B1"); 
        }
    }


public class C1 extends B1 {
    public void c1() {       
        System.out.println("C1"); 
    }
}

--------------------------  Adding New B1 Functionality to C1 ---------------------

public interface B_EXTRA {
    void b_extra();
}

public class B_EXTRA_IMPL implements B_EXTRA {

    public B1 m_b1;

    B_EXTRA_IMPL(B1 base) {
        m_b1 = base;
    }

    @Override
    public void b_extra() {
        System.out.println("b_extra");      

    }
}

public class C1X extends C1 implements B_EXTRA {
    B_EXTRA_IMPL b_extra;

    C1X() {
        super();
        b_extra = new B_EXTRA_IMPL((B1)this);
    }

    public void b1()
    {        
        System.out.println("B1"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void b_extra() {
        b_extra.b_extra();
    }   
}

public class D1 extends C1X {
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D1 d = new D1();
        d.b1();
        d.c1();
        d.b_extra();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just modify class B. No need for changes in other files.